# I can't read from DB using java netbeans

Tags: java

I have this code and I faced a problem to read information from MySQL database using java netbeans, data type inside database  varchar

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewDataBase {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb","root", "password");
              Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
              System.out.println("Enter name");
              String name =sc.next();
              String SQL = "select * from list where Name ='"+ name + "'";
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
              System.out.print("Name: " + rs.getNString("Name"));
              System.out.print("Number: " + rs.getNString("Number"));
              // while(rs.next())
              // {
              //   System.out.print("Name: " + rs.getNString("Name"));
              //  System.out.print("Number: " + rs.getNString("Number"));

              //}
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

---

Error:Can not call getNString() when field's charset isn't UTF-8

Comment: You're wide open for SQL injection. To avoid it, always make use of [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    props.put("user", "root");         
    props.put("password", "password");
    props.put("useUnicode", "true");
    props.put("useServerPrepStmts", "false"); // use client-side prepared statement
    props.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8"); // ensure charset is utf8 here

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

    PreparedStatement ps = 
        connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO list (Name, Number) VALUES (?, ?)");

    String testNumber = "12345";
    String testName = "name1";
    pstmt1.setNCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(testName), testName.length());
    ps.setNCharacterStream(2, new StringReader(testNumber), testNumber.length());
    ps.execute();
```

Also don't forget to comment in

```
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.print("Name: " + rs.getNString("Name"));
    System.out.print("Number: " + rs.getNString("Number"));
}
```

Comment: INSERT INTO list (Name, Number) VALUES (_utf8 'aaaaaa', _utf8 '222222');

Comment: Error:Can not call getNString() when field's charset isn't UTF-8

Comment: connect to database is done succesfully.
Update database is done succesfully by this statement:
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO list (Name, Number) VALUES (_utf8 'AB', _utf8 '45')");

but retreive data from database inside my program is not succeed
I think it's the type of data inside the database, what type of data that must be used.

thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Try  `rs.getString("Name")` instead of  `rs.getNString("Name")`.

Comment: Error:Before start of result se

Comment: Please add full error stacktrace and updated code. Half information may not help.

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure this works. This answer I got from Namberi.

```
rs.getString("Name") instead of rs.getNString("Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rs.next()) {
    rs.getString("Name");
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
```

And yes, better use a PreparedStatement for SQL injection and escaping of backslash, quote and such.